# Pycharm interpreter setting

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

There is a package list in the Pycharm-File-Settings-Project-Python interpreter(tf version = 1.10). When I input the "pip list" the terminal in pycharm(I could see the env_name has been activated in terminal), it shows a different package list(tf version = 1.11.9). does it means that there exist two different package lists in the same virtual env? If so, how to choose a specific one?

The interpreter is ~/anaconda2/envs/env_name/bin/python

Python version = 2.7.18::Anaconda, Inc.
conda version = 4.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with Anaconda, but I think it doesn't use pip to manage packages. You should run

`conda list --name env_name`

See also [this table](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html#conda-vs-pip-vs-virtualenv-commands).